# How to find the distribution of $X$, if $X|P$ is hypergeometric and $P$ is Beta?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a given $p$, a random variable $X$ follows hypergeometric distribution with pdf $P[X=x|P]=\dfrac{{Np \choose x}{Nq \choose n-x}}{{N \choose n}} ,\text{where} \ A \le X \le B, \ p+q=1$
$$P \sim \text{Beta}(a,b) ,\text{where}\ a>0,b>0 ,0<p<1$$
Find the distribution of $X$.

**My approach:**

Let the pdf of $X$ be $f(x)$ .
Then $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\beta(a,b)} p^{a-1}(1-p)^{b-1} \frac{{Np \choose x}{Nq \choose n-x}}{{N \choose n}} dp$$

But I am not able to calculate this integral.